# Wait for user close window to get values from NSTextField - Cocoa

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa

I am developing a GUI in Cocoa with a button and one NSTextField. When the button is clicked another window pop up with one NSTextField and two buttons: Ok button and Cancel Button. The user can entry some text in the NSTextField of the second window and when this window is closed the same text goes to the NSTextField of ther first window.

My question is: how can I make my application wait for the user to close the second window to update the NSTextField of the first widow? And if the user clicks the Cancel Button in the second window I don't wanna change anything in the first window.

Is it only possible with modal window?

Thanks in advance,

Rhenan

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple solution with a sheet

- In Interface Builder create a new window in the same .xib as the main window, size it smaller than the main window.
- Uncheck `Close`, `Minimize`, `Resize` and `Visible At Launch`.
  Make sure that `Title Bar` is checked (otherwise will break first responder).
- Add an NSTextField and two NSButtons, set the `tag` of the OK button to 1.
- In the .h file add

  ```
  @property (weak) IBOutlet NSTextField *textField;
  @property (weak) IBOutlet NSWindow *sheet;
  ```
- In the .m file add

  ```
  - (IBAction)showSheet:(id )sender
  {
    [self.window beginSheet:self.sheet completionHandler:^(NSModalResponse returnCode) {
      if (returnCode == NSModalResponseOK) {
         self.mainTextField.stringValue = self.textField.stringValue;
      }
    }];
  }

  - (IBAction)dismissSheet:(NSButton *)button
  {
     [self.textField.window makeFirstResponder:nil]; // force end editing
     [self.window endSheet:self.sheet returnCode:button.tag];
  }
  ```

`mainTextField`is the NSTextField instance in the main window

In the new created window in Interface Builder

- connect the NSWindow outlet to `IBOutlet sheet`
- connect the NSTextField outlet to `IBOutlet textField`
- connect the actions of both NSButtons to `IBAction dismissSheet`
- connect the action of the UI element to show the sheet to `IBAction showSheet`

Comment: I too suggest sheet window in this scenario . But If you don't want to use sheet window , you can use NSWindowWillClose delegate property.  example like this secondWindow.delegate = controller; //in your controller - (void)windowWillClose:(NSNotification *)notification{//update your text box in first window  }